# How to retrieve the single column data in parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have created a class called gameScore in Parse and added few columns to it as shown below.

```
var gameScore = PFObject(className:"GameScore")
gameScore["score"] = 1337
gameScore["playerName"] = "Sean Plott"
gameScore.saveInBackground()
```

Likewise, I have added 10 player names and their scores, now I want get all the player names.
I mean I want to retrieve only playerName column.

Can anybody please tell me how to do this!!!``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `PFQuery` for your `GameScore` and use `selectKeys:` to specify that only `playerName` is returned.

This does not change the maximum number of players that will be returned in any response...